# Springboot API not running in parallel for multiple API calls

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, microservices

I have a simple API that just prints Hello on the console. After printing, the thread sleeps for 10 seconds.

I hit this API thrice one after another within a second using postman.

Ideally, the print should happen as soon as the API is called but they happen at a gap of 10s each.

I'm not able to figure out why is this happening and how to make it work?

The API:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/print-hello")
public void printHello() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")) +  "Hello on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Console log (Note the ~10s difference in each):

```
2022-02-07T09:43:15.659257+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-10
2022-02-07T09:43:26.144665+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-1
2022-02-07T09:43:36.187410+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-3
```

**Update**:

I was able to make it print as soon as the API hits by creating a util function:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/print-hello")
public void printHello() throws InterruptedException {
    printHelloUtil();
}

public void printHelloUtil() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")) +  "Hello on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Output (Time difference now is just 1s):

```
2022-02-07T15:49:40.027275+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-9
2022-02-07T15:49:41.502248+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-10
2022-02-07T15:49:42.496611+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]Hello on http-nio-8080-exec-2
```

Still clueless about what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Unless you have anything working as a shared resource, it should work fine

Comment: The code contains just a print line, no shared resources involved.
Tried running on local as well as on Kubernetes. Always gets called in sequence.

Comment: How do you send the requests?

Comment: Using postman manually.

Comment: so they cant be considered parallel, they get executed in a sequence

Comment: But the print should happen as soon as the API is hit, but the print happens 10s after the previous print.

Comment: Your method is blocking by default, so it will wait that Thread.sleep() returns. If you want an async behaviour you can achieve it with @Async that will delegate the execution of your method to a task.

Comment: sleep might be holding println resources. You might need to do more research on println.

Comment: @MickaëlB. by default, on a prod environment, an API is accessible to only 1 request at a time?
If an API responds back in 5 seconds, does that mean other calls to the same API will wait?

Comment: No, each request is served in it's own thread and I suspect in your case, print resources are being held while the thread goes to sleep

Comment: Added an update, was able to make it work but still no reason justifies the behaviour

Comment: I'm suspecting that postman was the one waiting for the response to be received and not the server. Try simulating the same call using curl in 3 different terminal windows.

Comment: Hey @PradeepKrishnaGovindaraju, thanks for the reply.
I did try calling the same API in 3 different postman tabs. 
The first call responds back in 10s, second in 20s, third in 30s, hence indicating the waiting.

Comment: @AnshArora how are you sending all the 3 requests at once?  is that the delay in sending the requests.

Comment: Sending them one after another, but not with a 10s delay, maybe a second after each other. But the logs are being printed 10s apart due to the thread sleeping.